# Adding a space between a match in Sed

Tags: linux, sed

```
8167656.COMTXSFR.COMXYSJZT.NET256079.COMG-BEI.NET256702.COM516073.COMWBMSR.COMWCRHC.COMWBRZD.COMWCFGR.COM571095.COM5770879.COMWBRTK.COMYWRTF.COMDZJZPX.COM5770819.COMSFCZH.COM8733918.COMHSPCF.COMSFXHT.COMXJFPX.COMWCRGT.COMWCKYR.COMWBRHM.COMWBRYG.COMWCRGX.COMFXTMY.COM1313661.COMBKRQC.COMBKSQC.COMBLLQC.COM6880797.COMWCKKR.COMWCJKR.COM516097.COMFPCYS.COMDKDZS.COMWIN2010.NETSFMWM.COMFSHUAYUE.NET001DAO.NETEXQUISITEGIFT.NETBANTLN.COMW363888.NET8848K.NETV6789.COMSZJIAHUA.NETICJY.NETSUPVAR.NETHUALINONLINE.NE
```

That's an example of what I'm working with. I need to add a space after `(COM|NET|INFO)` so the domains are readable. I've tried a few different ways, but can't seem to get it to work. The regex should be `(\.INFO|\.COM|\.NET)` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape pipes in pattern:

```
sed 's/\(INFO\|COM\|NET\)/& /g' file
```

Comment: It appears that was the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` uses POSIX Basic Regular Expressions, and use of alteration (`|`) in BREs is a non-portable extension.

In this case, to substitute for multiple words a substitution (`s`) command is needed per-word:

```
sed 's/\.INFO/& /g;s/\.COM/& /g;s/\.NET/& /g'
```

`&` is substituted for the entire match.

Though a more concise solution would be to use `awk`, which supports Extended Regular Expressions and, by extension, alteration:

```
awk '{gsub(/\.(INFO|COM|NET)/, "& ")}1'
```